# Can a single column be excluded from the child row of a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am building a responsive DataTable that holds data for an application that can be used across multiple screen-types. Ideally people will be using iPad sized screens while on the floor and away from their desks, but they also want to make sure that someone can see this information while using a smartphone.

I have Responsive set up so that when the screen size gets too small to show all the columns in the row, an empty column appears at the front for the dropdown icon (my company has manually overwritten the +/- icon - they found it tacky) and other columns become part of the child row.

My problem is that at screen sizes where the hidden column is actually hidden, you can click on the row and show that column as part of the child row. Keeping in mind the fact that we ideally want to make it so that touchscreen users can simply tap anywhere on the row instead of the dropdown icon, is there a way to prevent a single column from becoming part of the child row?

Here is the table:

```
<table class="responsive display no-wrap" id="featuresList" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="max-mobile">&nbsp;</th>
            <th data-priority="10001">Permission Type</th>
            <th data-priority="1">Title</th>
            <th data-priority="10003">Description</th>
            <th data-priority="10003" style="text-align:center;">View</th>
            <th data-priority="10003" style="text-align:center;">Add</th>
            <th data-priority="10003" style="text-align:center;">Edit</th>
            <th data-priority="10003" style="text-align:center;">Delete</th>
            <th data-priority="1">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            Iterator<Feature> iter = user.getUserFeatures().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Feature feature = (Feature)iter.next();
            %>
            <tr class="no-wrap">
                <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-down chev"></i></td>
                <td>User</td>
                <td><%=feature.getTitle()%></td>
                <td><%=StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(feature.getDescription(), "")%></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><%if(feature.isHasView()){%><i class="fa fa-2x fa-check-circle"></i><%}%></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><%if(feature.isHasAdd()){%><i class="fa fa-2x fa-check-circle"></i><%}%></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><%if(feature.isHasEdit()){%><i class="fa fa-2x fa-check-circle"></i><%}%></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><%if(feature.isHasDelete()){%><i class="fa fa-2x fa-check-circle"></i><%}%></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a href="/Security/users.do?method=loadFeaturePermissions&featureID=<%=feature.getFeatureID()%>&userID=<%=userID%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#authorizeModal" class="btn btn-md btn-primary mb-1"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></i></a>
                    &nbsp;<a href="javascript:unathorizeUser('<%=feature.getTitle()%>','<%=feature.getFeatureID()%>','<%=userID%>');" class="btn btn-md btn-danger mb-1"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And here is the DataTable code:

```
$('#featuresList').DataTable({
    "fixedHeader":true,
    "searching":true,
    "bLengthChange":false,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "info":true,
    "language":{
    },
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 'tr'
        }
    },
    "columnDefs":[
        {"width":"5%", "targets":[0], "searchable":false,"orderable":false},
        {"width":"10%"},
        {"width":"20%"},
        {"width":"30%"},
        {"width":"5%"},
        {"width":"5%"},
        {"width":"5%"},
        {"width":"5%"},
        {"width":"15%", "targets":[8], "searchable":false,"orderable":false,"visible":true}
    ],
    "aaSorting":[]
});
```

Editing to add:

For some clarification on my question, I am including images of what my table looks like at a small screen (mobile sized) compared to something akin to an iPad or larger. The larger screen size has the chevron showing in a child row, and this is what I am trying to hide. I do not want this column to become a child row, but to still show on smaller screen sizes.

Mobile:

[image: Mobile table]

Larger Screen:

[image: Larger table]

Answer (score 0):

In your `columnDefs`, you can specify the responsive priority of the columns.   So just set it up so that the hidden row is the last thing to be collapsed when the screen gets small.   https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority

You can also add breakpoint class names to determine which columns show at particular sizes.  https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html

Comment: I don't think you fully understood my question, unless I am not using responsivePriority to its fullest potential. I am using the responsivePriority to order the columns that disappear and that works fine. My issue is that the column hidden on larger screens (class="max-mobile") shows as part of a child row on larger screens. Of course the row is closed by default and it does not look like you can click on the row and show any children, but it could happen and that's the issue we're trying to tackle. I added some images to my question.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding, thanks for the clarification!   So now if I understand, you have replaced the default `+` button to expand the rows with a chevron icon.  But that icon is appearing in the expanded list, because you have it set as its own column, instead of being a css ::before element (which is what the `+` is).  So you could maybe override their ::before element css and replace it with the chevron, and it would show/hide properly.  Or you could give that <td> and its associated <th> a class, and then write a breakpoint css that hides it above a certain size.